# How to create two run-times in a single Mobile First v7.1 server instance

Tags: websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-server, server-configuration

We are developing a MobileFirst Hybrid Application on MFPv7.1. On my MobileFirstv7.1 server we created a configuration and runtime for development environment  which has a runtime and where my application is currently running. Now my requirement is I want to setup a UAT environment on the same MobileFirst server instance. My question how to create make the UAT setup on the same MobileFirst server instance. Can I create a one more runtime on the same MobileFirst server by providing a new WAR file and can deploy my application (adapters pointing to UAT backend), by which I can have to two runtime in the same MobileFirst server configuration instance.

To make the question more clear, I have created two MobileFirst projects in my development MFP studio eclipse workspace 1)MyAppDEV which has MyApplication hybrid app and adapters pointing to Dev environemnt backend and 2)MyAppUAT also has same MyApplication hybrid app and same adapters such as project MyAppDEV, but app and adapter is pointing to UAT environment backend. But I can see the two projects running on the same MobileFirst server instance but with different runtime. Please find the below image for more understanding.

[image]

How to achieve the same implementation on my Liberty server.

Any help is very much appreciated. Can anyone please guide me how to achieve this.

Thanks & Regards,
Karthik S

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to repeat the same steps you have taken in order to deploy your single runtime to Liberty. You probably used either the configuration scripts (for the database, etc...) where you modified them with your .war filename, etc, or you've used the provided Configuration tool and specified the database name, .war filename, etc.

So you simply need to repeat the same steps you've previous taken, only now mention the second runtime details. Per your requirement, it sounds like it should be the same details, but different .war filename.

Note however that for a real topology you should create a *separate* environment all together and not re-use the same one for different purposes. A server for development, a server for QA, a serve for UAT and a server for production, instead of mixing them...

Comment: Hi Idan Adar, Thank you soo much for your response.